# How do I finnangle the type that linq outputs into the function's return type

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, backend

I have a function that looks like this:

```
 Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUserContactInfo(
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()
               )
        {
                var users = from u in _userDbContext.Users
                        join ur in _userDbContext.UserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                        select u;
            var u2 = users.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return u2;

        }
```

but.. attempting to compile it gives me this error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<System.Collections.Generic.List
>   <IPD.Identity.Domain.Aggregates.UserAggregate.User>>'`  to
>   `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IPD.Identity.Domain.Aggregates.UserAggregate.User>>'`

Any ideas about how to cast into the function's return type, or alternately attach something to the linq that will give back the right type, or really any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`ConfigureAwait` returns `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`, not `Task`. You need to await explicitly for that with `await` keyword, and change that method to be `async`.

But, you can just return `Task` without `ConfigureAwait(false)` as well and in that case nothing needs to be done apart adding `ConfigureAwait()` to the calling method.

So, just return `users.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);` from that method and call it so:

```
var info = await GetUserContactInfo(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In that case, as you are not using `await` inside that method, there is no need for `ConfigureAwait` after `ToListAsync()`.

***Update for comment:***

By the way, as return type of function is `Task<IEnumerable<...>`, you won'be able to return `Task<List<...>>`. Because, `Task<>` is not a covariant type. FOr solving that problem you can change return type to `Task<List<...>>`.

So result might be so:

```
Task<List<User>> GetUserContactInfo(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            var users = from u in _userDbContext.Users
                        join ur in _userDbContext.UserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                        select u;
            return users.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work.. I think the bigger problem is that I don't really understand how this async stuff works, but I still want to get the code to run.. I tried to stick configureAwait on it, and got the same error.

Comment: @מלךהמשיח Just remove `ConfigureAwait(false);` from that method. And check at first

Comment: Farhad,  I did.. and it didn't work.. gave yet another convoluted error.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<IPD.Identity.Domain.Aggregates.UserAggregate.User>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IPD.Identity.Domain.Aggregates.UserAggregate.User>>' IPD.Identity.Infrastructure C:\Users\michael.rubinstein\source\repos\IPD.Identity.ApiService\Src\IPD.Identity.Infrastructure\Repositories\UserRepository.cs 147 Active

Comment: @מלךהמשיח updtaed answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206606/discussion-between---and-farhad-jabiyev).